# Android: How to configure FFMPEG latest version in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video, ffmpeg

I want to configure `FFMPEG` in android studio but i cant get any document or link for that. Github on many `FFMPEG` lib available for android but that all are with old version. And how to run command in android? and i want to know after configure `FFMPEG` then how can we run `FFMPEG` commands. Help me for that. thanks advance.

I have used below links but not success in for latest version.

> http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java
>
> https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
>
> https://github.com/havlenapetr/FFMpeg
>
> https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg
>
> https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android

Comment: What do you mean by latest version of `FFMPEG` ?? I mean what is the difference between THE latest version and the links you provided above. I have worked with `FFMPEG` android and successfully created many videos..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya i want to use reverse command in with FFMPEG but not worked in all library that above provided link from

Comment: @jankigadhiya i need to use reverse command or easy to reverse video?

Comment: but latest version in available reverse command

Comment: I have performed it for NDK r12b see my answer update it is full setup for android studio..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya Have you done it with sdk too? I need help with sdk

Answer (score 37):

The latest version of `FFMPEG` is 3.1.1, Just released before 12 days. So i think there is no [readily available demo like this old](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) one.

We need to build the `FFMPEG` library on our own. Some questions i found just pasting here that might help you. (Not tested)

**How to Build FFmpeg for Android**

1. [Compiling FFmpeg 2.3 with Android NDK r10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853599/compiling-ffmpeg-2-3-with-android-ndk-r10)
2. [How to compile ffmpeg-2.5.3 on windows with android-ndk-r10d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901708/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-2-5-3-on-windows-with-android-ndk-r10d)
3. [How to compile ffmpeg-2.2.2 on windows with cygwin and android ndk r9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683518/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-2-2-2-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r9c)
4. [How to buid ffmpeg with android-ndk-r10d in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874153/how-to-buid-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk-r10d-in-windows)

You need to compile it on your own the by downloading [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) & [Latest Version of `FFMPEG`](https://ffmpeg.org/).

One tutorial is also there : [How to Build FFmpeg for Android](http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/17/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/). This is quite old so you just need to change the versions mentioned here. For `FFMPEG` it will be `3.1.1` & NDK it will be `r12b`.

---

**Building `FFMPEG` with NDK r12b:**

1. **Download Android NDK** : The latest version of Android NDK can be downloaded at [Android NDK website](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html). At the time of writing this answer, the newest version is NDK r12. simply decompress the archive
2. **Download ffmpeg source code** : FFMPEG source code can be downloaded from the [ffmpeg website](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html). The latest stable release is 3.1.1 (at the time of writing). Download the source code and decompress it to $NDK/sources folder.
3. **Update configure file :** Open ffmpeg-3.1.1/configure file with a text editor, and locate the following lines.

   ```
   SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBNAME).$(LIBMAJOR)'
   LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
   SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION)'
   SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR) $(SLIBNAME)'
   ```

   This cause ffmpeg shared libraries to be compiled to
   libavcodec.so. (e.g. libavcodec.so.55), which is not
   compatible with Android build system. Therefore we’ll need to replace
   the above lines with the following lines.

   ```
   SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBPREF)$(FULLNAME)-$(LIBMAJOR)$(SLIBSUF)'
   LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
   SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)'
   SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME)
   ```
4. **Build ffmpeg :** Copy the following text to a text editor and save it as build_android.sh in ffmpeg_3.1.1 folder.

   ```
       #!/bin/bash
       NDK=$HOME/Desktop/adt/android-ndk-r9
       SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
       TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
       function build_one
       {
           ./configure
               --prefix=$PREFIX
               --enable-shared
               --disable-static
           --disable-doc
                   --disable-ffmpeg
               --disable-ffplay
               --disable-ffprobe
               --disable-ffserver
               --disable-avdevice
               --disable-doc
               --disable-symver
               --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
               --target-os=linux
               --arch=arm
               --enable-cross-compile
               --sysroot=$SYSROOT
               --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS"
               --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS"
           $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
           make clean
           make
           make install
       }
       CPU=arm
       PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
       ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
       build_one
   ```

   Once the file is saved, go to the directory where this file lies & execute the command below,

   ```
   sudo chmod +x build_android.sh
   ```

   Then execute the script by the command,

   ```
   ./build_android.sh
   ```
5. **Build Output :** The build can take a while to finish depending on your computer speed. Once it’s done, you should be able to find a folder $NDK/sources/ffmpeg-3.1.1/android, which contains arm/lib and arm/include folders.
6. **Make ffmpeg Libraries available for Your Projects**

> Steps above are fully tested and i performed them on my machine and
>   the build was successful. For writing this answer i have took the
>   reference from this article [How to Build ffmpeg with NDK
>   r9](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)
>   but as it was for older version i have made some corrections on my
>   own.

Open for asking any doubts.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel see this : http://superuser.com/questions/163049/what-is-the-equivalent-of-chmod-777

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117406/discussion-between-jaydeep-patel-and-janki-gadhiya).

Comment: Hi am using ubundu and after executing this line ./build_android.sh it is showinng /configure: 3244: ./configure: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
./build_android.sh: line 8: --prefix=/home/techniche/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r12b/sources/ffmpeg-3.1.3/android/arm: No such file or directory

Comment: I was able to use you script successful for **ffmpeg 3.1.4**, but after finish there are no **android** folder (step 5) with output, instead there are folders with `.o`, `.d`, make files, etc. How to get `.so`?

Comment: hi @jankigadhiya .. i found problem in executing build_android.sh error:./build_android.sh: line 8: --prefix=/home/controller/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ffmpeg-3.2.2/android/arm: No such file or directory

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did what you said, but I get this error : ./build_android.sh: 34: ./build_android.sh: build_one: not found !!!

Comment: Can I use the direct library of GitHub instead of this lengthy process or this is the must?

Comment: I have tried to run cacls +x build_ffmpeg_android.sh for Window and then build_ffmpeg_android.sh because ./ was giving the error but Android folder not creating why?
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64

Comment: @JankiGadhiya Please help me to configure ffmpeg lib for windows

Answer (score 13):

> **I suggest you these following URLs that was helpful for me :**
>
> http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html
>
> http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
>
> https://androiddeveloperhelp.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/video-editing-android-example/
>
> **For knowledge:**
>
> http://www.lai18.com/content/5175900.html
>
> **Android studio Source Code:**
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qAjo6wKhk9MEpNNjMxaG5oWXM/view?usp=sharing
>
> It may be help you.

Comment: i want to use latest version of FFMPEG

Comment: Thank you. You save my 2 to 3 days.

Comment: @RaviVaghela : have you found any solution for latest version?

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen this link **Writingminds**'s FFmpeg library provided all explanation about it in [**this link**](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/)

### Latest Version of that library writingmind is here https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/releases[image]

If you want to use latest version of any library you can do it right from in `build.gradle` because if any library is not updated it can be seen and can be updated from `build.gradle`, I always do this for many library for latest available version.

For gradle in FFMpeg use this

```
compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

More libraries similar to it is given on this link
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/925

Also i suggest you to read [this que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android), and [this que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871297/ffmpeg-android-wrapper-using-the-latest-versions-off-ffmpeg?rq=1)

### If you want to use Latest version of Original Library go here : [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) **[ latest version will be [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) ]**

to add with native code then these blogs may help you

http://ffmpeg-android.blogspot.in/ and

http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/17/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/

Comment: i want to use latest version of FFMPEG

Comment: I have already mentioned twise in my answer for latest version @RaviVGHL this link i have given you in my answer is giving it http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/   and you can update latest library version directly from build.gradle

Comment: but here no any latest version build with this library

Comment: I have already provided that also in my answer from official site you can always get latest version. 
 https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: This is out of dated dependency. Please update your answer

Comment: can you please edit this as I am no longer working on Java and android and not sure what version you are asking for? @AnandSavjani

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced with ffmpeg for android for few weeks.

The library called FFmpeg4Android and can be found [here at WarZone](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html).

I know the title says it from December 6, 2011 but i've tested and worked with it and it all runs smoothly. You haven't mentioned what's your exact need with this library but you could read about the ffmpeg abilities at the [official site](https://ffmpeg.org/).

The FFmpeg4Android has an example project that can be a great reference, and also their support is immediate and clear.

The commands are running according to your string input, e.g:

**ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -s 160x120 -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 150k -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4**

let me know if you need further help, i'll be glad to help.