# Build FFMPEG 3.1.4 for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I used [this](http://ffmpeg-android.blogspot.com) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328783/3226984) methods to build latest (3.1.4) **[FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)** version for Android.
Build was succeed.
I got several folders with `sources` / `headers` / `.o` files.
But unfortunately there are no `.so` files I need.
Are there some updated script for building latest **[FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org)** for android?
Or, how to convert `.o` and other files to `.so`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've actually posted this as a few answers now. This works perfectly for ffmpeg 3.1.4:

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

function build_it {
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX    \
    --disable-static    \
    --enable-shared     \
    --disable-doc       \
    --disable-ffmpeg    \
    --disable-ffplay    \
    --disable-ffprobe   \
    --disable-ffserver  \
    --disable-avdevice  \
    --disable-doc       \
    --disable-symver    \
    --cross-prefix=$CPREFIX \
    --target-os=linux   \
    --arch=arm      \
    --enable-cross-compile  \
    --enable-gpl        \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT  \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
    make clean
    make -j9
    make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_it
```

You will find the android libraries and headers in android/arm/...

Comment: It generates `.a` (static libraries), how about `.so`? Thank you anyway, I think I can use static libraries as well.

Comment: --enable-shared or static will give you the right libs .so or .a

Comment: it generates `.so`s for me. how do I get `.a` ?

Comment: Switch between `--enable-shared` and `--enable-static` to what you need. Don't forget to disable the other.