# Can't use ffmpeg 3.2 in Android project

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

Tried almost everything, spent almost 4-5 days trying and still counting.

The reason I want to compile recent version of ffmpeg is because https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java doesn't work for video rotation. For this also I tried multiple answers, different versions of answer (transpose=1, transpose=dir=cclock, etc)

Somewhere it was mentioned that rotate command wont work with previous versions of ffmpeg, so after a lot of trials, I started working on compilation of new ffmpeg. But all the tutorials for ffmpeg belong to earlier versions (of Android NDk, ffmpeg) which wont work with ffmpeg 3.2 and NDK r13b (I also tried with NDK downloaded by studio itself but no luck). In case it worked for you, please help.

After a lot of frustrating experience I am writing this. Please help with a workflow or a clear direction. Thanks

Wasnt able to tag ffmpeg3.2 because of reputation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40157208/2979092 works with 3.2 also...

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already compiled ffmpeg but not able to use it in my android project. any flow for this task? Adding compiled ffmpeg/Android in Android project

Comment: Take a look at my answer here for how to add it to your gradle script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38477333/2979092 Good luck.

Comment: @WLGfx thanks for replying. I will update you on the progress. Meanwhile can you have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749854/cant-rotate-video-android-ffmpeg

Comment: I hope you crack it finally. I'm sorry I can't help you with the other issue as I don't use the command line ffmpeg often and the only filter I've used so far is the yadif deinterlacing filter.