# ffmpeg build error looks tmp file creat fail?

Tags: android, linux, gcc, ffmpeg, android-ndk

```
 ./configure --target-os=android --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --enable-cross-compile --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-asm --arch=arm \
  --cc=$PREBUILT/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
  --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --disable-stripping --nm=$PREBUILT/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm --sysroot=$PLATFORM --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-small  --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffplay --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffserver --disable-debug --extra-cflags="-fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a"
```

this is out put log:

```html
Makefile:2: config.mak: 没有那个文件或目录
Makefile:67: /common.mak: 没有那个文件或目录
Makefile:109: /libavutil/Makefile: 没有那个文件或目录
Makefile:109: /library.mak: 没有那个文件或目录
Makefile:111: /doc/Makefile: 没有那个文件或目录
Makefile:198: /tests/Makefile: 没有那个文件或目录
make: *** No rule to make target '/tests/Makefile'。 停止。
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

but my gcc path works fine

`/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

I seems the temp file not create ,I can't find temp file in /tmp

this is end of config.log file:

```html
dition: defined __ARM_ARCH_6T2__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_6T2"
  ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
check_cpp_condition stddef.h defined __ARM_ARCH_7__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
    1   #include <stddef.h>
    2   #if !(defined __ARM_ARCH_7__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7)
    3   #error "unsatisfied condition: defined __ARM_ARCH_7__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7"
    4   #endif
END /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -isysroot /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a -E -o /tmp/ffconf.csA8Jm6F.o /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
/tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c:3:2: error: #error "unsatisfied condition: defined __ARM_ARCH_7__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7"
 #error "unsatisfied condition: defined __ARM_ARCH_7__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7"
  ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
check_cpp_condition stddef.h defined __ARM_ARCH_7A__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7_A
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
    1   #include <stddef.h>
    2   #if !(defined __ARM_ARCH_7A__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7_A)
    3   #error "unsatisfied condition: defined __ARM_ARCH_7A__ || defined __TARGET_ARCH_7_A"
    4   #endif
END /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -isysroot /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a -E -o /tmp/ffconf.csA8Jm6F.o /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -isysroot /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a -march=armv7-a -c -o /tmp/ffconf.csA8Jm6F.o /tmp/ffconf.FHwGDPbC.c
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -isysroot /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-arm -march=armv7-a -o /tmp/ffconf.fjKb0Qb0 /tmp/ffconf.csA8Jm6F.o
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lc
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
C compiler test failed.
```

Comment: "this is out put log" - probably incomplete as commands that resulted in error are not printed.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/40157208/2979092 for a working android build script to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Default NDK toolchain is unsuitable for compiling Autoconf projects. You'll need to generate standalong toolchain as described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html#creating_the_toolchain). If this does not help, you should examine the failing command in `config.log` and see what exactly goes wrong (simple gcc test won't help as errors may be caused by linker).

Comment: thanks ,I will post config.log content, I change a compute use ndk-r10 works fine