# Overlaying a [PNG] image while recording a video camera api android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want to add a png image while recording video using camera api, the image must acts as a watermark on the video while video is saved.

Answer (score 0):

One approach which I can suggest is use `ffmpeg` for android ([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328783/2930834)).
 You will need to compile the library yourself, if you want the latest version. 
 Readily available `ffmpeg` for android is [this](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java).
After implementing the `ffmpeg`, refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/2930834) for adding watermark.
Hope this helps.